# Regular Expression Java XML pig

Tags: java, xml, regex, apache-pig

Help please! Your few minutes could save me hours!!

I am using PIG to get a few info.

```xml
<Content

<Name ><\Name> 
<Data ><\Data>
<Data ><\Data>
><\Content>
```

So I used:

```
abcd_ = LOAD 'parentFolder/*' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Content') AS (content: chararray);
```

I only need a few specific info, I don't know about the possibility of:

```
 abcd_ = LOAD 'parentFolder/*' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Content','Data') AS (content: chararray,data: chararray);
```

but I wish to avoid that. I have successfully extracted my other infos using regex after the XMLLoader except the following (just an example of possible combination of characters)

```
<Data Name="Buffer">{&quot;$type&quot;System.Collections.Generic'[!#%,:()!@-;[.}<\Data>
```

My regular expression:

```
1. \\<Data Name=\\"Buffer\\"\\>\\{(.*)\\}\\<\Data\\> -- Unexpected character D at <\Data>
2. \\<Data Name=\\"Buffer\\"\\>\\{(.*)\\}\\<\\Data\\> -- I got nothing
3. \<Data Name=\"Buffer\"\>\{(.*)\}\<\\Data\> -- Unexpected character < at \<Data Name..
4. \\<Data Name=\\"Buffer\\"\\>\\{(.*)\\}\\<\\\Data\\> -- Unexpected character D at <\\\Data>
```

I intended to get:

```
&quot;$type&quot;System.Collections.Generic'[!#%,:()!@-;[.
```

Edit:

1. Just realized a huge mistake, \ should be /
2. Found the answer

   ```
   <Data Name=\\"Buffer\\">\\{(.*)\\}</Data\\>
   ```

Comment: You will be better off if you parsed your xml properly instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: I see, will try and see if that thing I am avoiding is possible.

Comment: Eh cannot man, I am quite new to big data and xml, what do you mean by parsing my xml properly actually? Could you explain a little bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to parse this XML would be to use the XPath Java API.

The following prints:

> XXXYYYZZZ
>
> 111222333

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.AbstractList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParseXML {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String input = "<Content><Data Name=\"Buffer\">XXXYYYZZZ</Data><Data Name=\"Buffer\">111222333</Data></Content>";
        String xpathExpression = "//Data[@Name='Buffer']";
        NodeList result = parseXML(input, xpathExpression);
        for (Node node : new NodeListWrapper(result)) {
            System.out.println(node.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
        }
    }

    private static NodeList parseXML(String input, String xpathExpression) throws Exception {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
        Document document = createDocument(input);
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
        return (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    }

    private static Document createDocument(String input) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(input)));
    }

}

class NodeListWrapper extends AbstractList<Node> {
    private final NodeList nodeList;

    public NodeListWrapper(NodeList nodeList) {
        this.nodeList = nodeList;
    }

    @Override
    public Node get(int n) {
        return nodeList.item(n);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return nodeList.getLength();
    }
}
```

I have uploaded my answer source code to GitHub [here](https://github.com/stevendoolan/stackoverflow/blob/master/parsexml/src/main/java/ParseXML.java).